# Caesar cipher exercise

Tags: python, beginner, programming-challenge, python-3.x, caesar-cipher

I was doing this exercise from [here](http://cscircles.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/15c/).  I made a solution work but can't help feel it could have been done in fewer lines.  I'm quite new to python so I'm not too sure of the little shortcuts.

```
def shift(S, n):
   word = ''
   for i in S:
      if ord(i) == 32:
         word += ' '
      elif ord(i)+n > 90:
         a = n-(90-ord(i))+64
         word += chr(a)
      else:
         word +=chr(ord(i)+n)
   return word
def TGS(x): # Total goodness of string
   TGC = 0 # Total goodness of character
   for i in x:
      if ord(i) == 32:
         continue
      TGC += letterGoodness[ord(i)-65]
   return TGC
A = input()
LOSS = [shift(A,n) for n in range (1,27)] # List of shifted strings
LOTG = [TGS(x) for x in LOSS]
a = LOTG.index(max(LOTG))
print(LOSS[a])
```

Comment: Consider using [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **Magic numbers**.

  Try to avoid them. 65 is really `ord('A')`, 90 is `ord('Z')`; so say that explicitly. Along the same line,

  ```
  if i == ' ':
  ```

  looks better than

  ```
  if ord(i) == 32:
  ```
- **Naming**

  Try to use descriptive names. I'd prefer `caesar_decrypt(ciphertext, shift)` to `shift(S, n)`. Same goes for `A`, `a`, etc.
- **Streamlining**

  I was really stumbled upon an asymmetry of `elif` and `else` cases of `shift`:

  ```
       a = n-(90-ord(i))+64
       word += chr(a)
  ```

  is quite counter-intuitive. I'd suggest

  ```
  for i in S:
    if ord(i) == 32:
        word += ' '
        continue
    a = ord(i) + n
    if a > ord('Z'):
        a -= ord('Z') - ord('A')
    word +=chr(a)
  ```

Comment: thanks for the reply, i will make those amendments, is there any way I can improve the last bit? It seems long winded.

Answer (score 3):

While you are by no means obligated to use it, here is a shorter version of the shift function.

With comments:

```
def shift(s,n):
    word=''
    for i in s:
        x=ord(i)
        y=x+n
        if 64<x<91:
            word+=chr(y) if y<91 else chr(65+y-90) 
        else:
            word+=' ' 
    return word
```

Explanation:

`y` is the ascii value plus the shift value.

`64<x<91` checks if the character is a character we are looking for.

`word+=chr(y) if y<91 else chr(65+y-90)` The shifted character will be added if it does not exceed 'Z', otherwise will equal the wraparound value.

**EDIT**

If you would prefer not to use a conditional expression, you could alternatively do this:

```
def shift(s,n):
    word=''
    for i in s:
        x=ord(i)
        y=x+n
        if 64<x<91:
            if y<91:
                word+=chr(65+y-90)
            else:
                word+=chr(y) 
        else:
            word+=' ' 
    return word
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the review, do you think there's a simpler way of doing the last bit? Creating two lists seems a bit long winded.

Comment: @VimalKarsan While I think the first is less verbose, I gave you an alternative process.

Comment: thank you but I was referring to the very last bit with the LOSS and LOTG where I'm finding the string with the highest 'goodness'. I know you can implement the max function with a key (using methods), is there a similar way to use max with a function key? Many thanks

Comment: You can pass the ordering function to `max` as keyword `key`: `max(LOSS, key=TGS)`.

Comment: if y>90: works better.  chr(65+y-91) also helps.

Answer (score 2):

Let's see.

1. I think s is a bit short.  I would use a longer word.
2. It is more readable to compare chars than the numeric equivalent
3. You could take care of negative values of n by adding if n<0: n = n%26+26
4. You could ignore any non-alphabetic letters and preserve punctuation.
5. You could also shift lowercase letters in a separate test.
6. Modular arithmetic can be used to shift a value in a circular way.  But you need to transform your letter into an integer in range 0..25.  And back.

Result:

```
def shift(string,n):
    if n<0:
        n = n%26 + 26
    word = ''
    for c in string:
        if 'A' <= c <= 'Z':
            c = chr((ord(c)-ord('A')+n)%26 + ord('A'));
        if 'a' <= c <= 'z':
            c = chr((ord(c)-ord('a')+n)%26 + ord('a'));
        word += c
    return word

print shift("Hello, World!", 3)
print shift("Khoor, Zruog!", -3)
```